# Integrating Ghostscript with TeX

Tags: installing, mactex, ghostscript, latexit

Making this copy of my [original question](https://superuser.com/q/1787105/1316866) on SuperUser was closest this question could be in the intersection of the two websites.

---

I performed the following steps:

1. Reinstalled macOS **Ventura 13.4** on my system. (I was taken aback to not find `/usr/local/bin/`, but then [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/280452/495879) provided relief.)
2. Installed Homebrew. (It is in `/opt` as expected.)
3. Did `brew install --cask xquartz`. This

   - installed `X11/` in `/opt/`,
   - added `XQuartz.app` in `/Applications/`, and
   - created symlinks X11 and X11R6 in `/usr/`, both pointing to `X11/` in `/opt`.
4. Did `brew install --cask mactex`. This resulted in things including:

   - Installed `texlive/` in `/usr/local`.
   - Installed `ghostscript/` in `/opt/Homebrew/Cellar/`.
   - Installed `TeX/` containing TeXShop, etc. in `/Applications/`.

(I have everything updated to the latest at I write. Also, I cross-verified the md5 checksum of `.pkg`.)

Now, when I tried to run LaTeXiT, it greeted me with the following error:

[image]

I went through the `READ ME FIRST.pdf` that came with the applications which mentions:

> Ghostscript installs support files in `/usr/local/share/ghostscript/10.00.0` and a few binaries in `/usr/local/bin`. In particular, it installs `gs-X11` and `gs-noX11` in `/usr/local/bin`, where the first requires X11 and the second does not. Then MacTeX installs a symbolic link `gs` pointing to the first binary if the user’s machine has X11, and to the second binary otherwise. New versions of Ghostscript can be installed over version 10.00 without removing 10.00 first.

This documentation doesn't seem to be updated with the fact that Homebrew's prefix is in `/opt/Homebrew/` for Apple Silicon: `/usr/local/share/` should have been `/opt/Homebrew/Cellar`.

Next, I still don't have `usr/local/bin`, wherein to find `gs-X11` and `gs-noX11`. In fact, a Finder search yields no results for these.

Furthermore, from the [MacTeX website](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html):

> The TeX Live programs `xdvi`, `pdfopen`, and `pdfclose` require X11. In addition, the Ghostscript library `libgs` requires X11 (but notice that `dvisvgm` is the only TeX Live program using it). Ghostscript comes with two binaries, `gs-X11` and `gs-noX11`, where `gs-X11` has support for X11 and `gs-noX11` does not. When Ghostscript is first installed, a symbolic link named `gs` is created in `/usr/local/bin`. If X11 is present, `gs` points to `gs-X11`; otherwise it points to `gs-noX11`. On Arm machines, `gs` points to `gs-X11` only if XQuartz 2.8.0 or higher is present.

**Questions:**

1. Where are `gs-X11`, `gs-noX11`, and the symlink `gs` on my system?
2. How to have everything integrated, so that TeX detects Ghostscript, and LaTeXiT works fine?

Comment: On my Mac (running Ventura), `mdfind -name gs-X11` returns `/usr/local/bin` and indeed it is there. I installed everything using Mac TeX rather than a mix of Mac TeX and Homebrew. If you used the latter, then yes there will be some differences in the documentation due to where Homebrew puts things on Apple Silicon systems. It's a bit of a mess.

Comment: Unfortunately, `sudo find / -name gs-noX11 2>/dev/null` give me empty result. 